# How to get values from an AsyncTask when it is in another class

Tags: java, android, android-room

I need to get the result from my AsyncTask. I can actually get the result from the task but I just don't know how to get it from  the method that needs it. As will see, the AsyncTask is in a different class. If you have a question so I can clarify, please tell me so I can edit the post. See my code below:

```
public class UserRepository {
    private UserDao userDao;
    private User user;
    private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;

    public UserRepository(Application application) {
        AtsDatabase database = AtsDatabase.getInstance(application);
        userDao = database.userDao();
        allUsers = userDao.getUsers();
    }

 private MutableLiveData<User> userSearched = new MutableLiveData<>();
 private void asyncFinished(User userResult) {
    if(userResult == null) return;
    Log.i("TAG", "asyncFinished: " + userResult.getLastName());
    userSearched.setValue(userResult);
 }

    public LiveData<User> getUserByUserName(String userName) {
        new GetUserByUserNameAsyncTask(userDao).execute(userName); ===> I NEED THE RESULT HERE SO I CAN PASS IT TO MY VIEW MODEL
    }

    public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers() { return allUsers; }

    private static class InsertUserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<User, Void, Void> {
        private UserDao userDao;

        private InsertUserAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) { this.userDao = userDao; }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(User... users) {
            userDao.insert(users[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class GetUserByUserNameAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User> {
        private LiveData<User> user;
        private UserDao userDao;

        private GetUserByUserNameAsyncTask(UserDao userDao) { this.userDao = userDao; }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(String... strings) {
             user = userDao.getUserByUserName(strings[0]); ======> I GET RESULT HERE 
             return null;
        }

         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
        super.onPostExecute(user);
        Log.i("TAG", "onPostExecute: "+user.getLastName());
        delegate.asyncFinished(user);
    }
    }
}
```

How do I make this right?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `AsyncTask` is now deprecated.

If you still want to use it, create a `MutableLiveData` and 
return it as a `LiveData` in the exposed function, then pass it through the constructor of the `AsyncTask`.
Use the `postValue` method of the `MutableLiveData` to set the result after you get it.

Comment: Since the AsyncTask is depectated, what should I use in lieu of it then?

Comment: consider using methods from `java.util.concurrent` package (or coroutines if you want to switch to Kotlin) as stated in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: I am able to do it in Kotlin. I am trying to do it in Java. I'll give the concurrent a try.

Comment: I have updated my question  to what you suggested on asynctask. I get an error on the onPostExecute as `Attempt to invoke direct method 'void UserRepository.asyncFinished(com.ats.atsver2.ui.db.classes.User)' on a null object reference`